# Probability proof - correlation coefficient.

Tags: probability

Probability proof: $\rho_{XY}\in \{-1,1\}$ iff there exist $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $Y=aX+b$ is almost sure, where $\rho_{XY}$ is correlation coefficient.

I have proofs for the following properties of correlation coefficient:
$\rho_{XX}=1, \rho_{XY}=\rho_{YX},|\rho_{XY}|\le 1,$ if $X,Y$ are independent random variables, then $\rho_{XY}=0$.

How to prove this statement? Is it possible to prove it by using above mensioned proofs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be random variables with $0<\sigma_X^2<\infty$ and $0<\sigma_Y^2<\infty$.

Then defining $U_X:=\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$ and $U_Y:=\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}$ we have:$$\rho_{X,Y}=\mathbb EU_XU_Y$$
If $a\neq0$ and $b$ are fixed then it can be shown (try it yourself) that: $$U_{aX+b}=\frac{a}{|a|}U_X$$ and consequently we find:$$\rho_{X,aX+b}=\frac{a}{|a|}\rho_{X,X}$$
Knowing that $\rho_{X,X}=1$ under these conditions (you have a proof for it), we end up with:$$\rho_{X,aX+b}=\frac{a}{|a|}\in\{-1,1\}$$

---

Hint for converse:

If $\rho_{X,Y}=1$ then $\mathbb E(U_X-U_Y)^2=0$ hence $U_X-U_Y=0$ a.s.

If $\rho_{X,Y}=-1$ then $\mathbb E(U_X+U_Y)^2=0$ hence $U_X+U_Y=0$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The fact that $|\rho_{XY}| \leq 1$ is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$|\langle v,w \rangle| \leq \|v\| \|w\|$$ applied in the space of square-integrable random variables *modulo constants*.

Equality holds in Cauchy-Schwarz *if and only if* one vector is a scalar multiple of another.